# MYSQL DISTINCT on one column PLUS oher values

Tags: mysql

I wish to retrieve ordno and invno where ordno is unique from two different tables (archived and none archived invoices). The closest I have come is using the following using UNION DISTINCT but I also need the invno - any help is welcome?

```
SELECT INInvoiceHeaders.ordno
FROM INInvoiceHeaders 
WHERE (MONTH(INInvoiceHeaders.invdate)=11  
  AND YEAR(INInvoiceHeaders.invdate)=2016) 
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT INArchivedInvoiceHeaders.ordno
FROM INArchivedInvoiceHeaders 
WHERE (MONTH(INArchivedInvoiceHeaders.invdate)=11 
  AND YEAR(INArchivedInvoiceHeaders.invdate)=2016)
GROUP BY ordno
```

Comment: If there can be duplicate `ordno` and you are eliminating them using UNION DISTINCT, it's not clear which `invno` would need to be selected from the group of duplicates. An example would probably help.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT(table1.ordno), table1.invno 
> FROM ...
> ```

You can't use `DISTINCT` like that, it is not a function. It's a modifier (of the `SELECT` or `UNION` clause) and it applies to all the row, not a single column.

You can use `GROUP BY` instead and `MIN()` function to find the smallest inventory number for each order, in each table.
Then use `UNION` (`ALL`, not `DISTINCT`) to get these results from both tables.
Then `GROUP BY` again in case some inventory numbers appear in both tables:

```
SELECT ordno, MIN(invno) AS invno
FROM
  ( SELECT ordno, MIN(invno) AS invno
    FROM INInvoiceHeaders 
    WHERE invdate >= DATE '2016-11-01' 
      AND invdate  < DATE '2016-11-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ordno, MIN(invno)
    FROM INArchivedInvoiceHeaders 
    WHERE invdate >= DATE '2016-11-01' 
      AND invdate  < DATE '2016-11-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
    GROUP BY ordno 
  ) AS t 
GROUP BY ordno ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You indeed need to use a union and then join the invoices on the result, something like this:

```
select o.*, i* from (select id from orders union all select id from arch_orders group by id ) as o left join invoices as i on i.order_id = o.id
```

}